# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform, image-rotation

I have an UIImageView and I wanted to rotate it slightly in the anti-clock direction. But when I do that, rotation works. But the edges are not shared. Having a pixelated edges. How do I solve this issue. Please help.

```
UIImageView *popupTop = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 54, 300, 15)];
popupTop.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pover_note.png"];
[self.view addSubview:popupTop];

popupTop.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0.04);
```

Comment: Could you please show the original image, and the edgy result as well?

Answer (score 3):

Add a key in info.plist
**Renders with edge antialisasing** and set its value to YES

Comment: ya it may be cause some performance issue but you can try it and check whether the performance issue is noticeable or not and if not then your problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

There is a key that you can set in Info.plist that enables antialiasing of the edges: `UIViewEdgeAntialiasing` .

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a potential performance hit or possible other side effects of `UIViewEdgeAntialiasing` then the easiest way is to make a border of transparent pixels around your image :)

Comment: I don't want to have any performance issue. Can you please tell me how to add transparent border around image? I tried this. But no luck.

Comment: `code`CGRect imageRrect = CGRectMake(0, 0, popupTop.image.size.width, popupTop.image.size.height);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageRrect.size); 
        [popupTop.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(1,1, popupTop.image.size.width-2, popupTop.image.size.height-2)];
        popupTop.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); `code`

Comment: No, I mean literally _in the image_ - use Photoshop :)